# Angular 11, Child Component Isn't Receiving Nested API Object from Parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, rxjs

I have been stuck on this problem for a few days and just can't quite figure out what is going wrong. Here's the Flow of the application:

Call API -> Receive Response -> Display Results in Parent Component ->
Pass Results from Parent to Child When a User Clicks a Result.

The last step is what is causing me this headache, I for the life of me cannot seem to pass a nested result from my Parent(**missionList**) to my Child Component(**misionDetails**)

In the Child Components HTML file it throws an error saying *Property 'mission_small_patch' does not exist on type 'ILinks[]'*

The weird part is, if I just re-save my Interface file, the application will reload and then display the image in the Child Component! This is whats so confusing to me, I know that the property exists & I believe I am accessing it correctly.

I just don't know what I'm overlooking here. Could it be the way I display the data in the Parent, by using a custom pipe? I have also tried changing the getMission() method in the parent to map the values
similar to this & still no change:

```js
getMission():void{
 this.service.subscribe((resp:any)=>{
    this.mission_patch_small = resp.map(r => r.links)
})
}
```

The external API  (https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches) response gives me a nested object, I am specifically targeting **links**: **mission_patch_small**

```json
"flight_number": 1,
"mission_name": "FalconSat",
 "launch_failure_details": {
      "time": 33,
      "altitude": null,
      "reason": "merlin engine failure"
    },
    "links": {
      "mission_patch": "https://images2.imgbox.com/40/e3/GypSkayF_o.png",
      "mission_patch_small": "https://images2.imgbox.com/3c/0e/T8iJcSN3_o.png",
      "reddit_campaign": null,
      "reddit_launch": null,
      "reddit_recovery": null,
      "reddit_media": null,
      "presskit": null,
      "article_link": "https://www.space.com/2196-spacex-inaugural-falcon-1-rocket-lost-launch.html",
      "wikipedia": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DemoSat",
      "video_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a_00nJ_Y88",
      "youtube_id": "0a_00nJ_Y88",
      "flickr_images": []
    },
```

Here is my interface for the received data, you can see that
I have one unnecessary field, *mission_patch_small*, I had added it for
debugging purposes as I just cannot access this property for the life of me! I have also tried changing the type of *mission_patch_small* to
**mission_patch_small : string[]**  & no luck. I did this for mapping the links url in the getMission() method described above

```js
export interface IMission {
  mission_name: string;
  launch_year: string;
  details: string;
  mission_patch_small: string;
  links: ILinks[];
}

export interface ILinks {
  mission_patch_small: string[];
}
```

Here is how I am fetching the data using HttpClient & RxJs Observables

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IMission } from '../models/mission';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpacexapiService {
  baseURL: string = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMission(): Observable<IMission[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMission[]>(this.baseURL);
  }

  

}
```

Here is my missionList.component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IMission } from '../models/mission';
import { SpacexapiService } from '../network/spacexapi.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-missionlist',
  templateUrl: './missionlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./missionlist.component.css'],
})
export class MissionlistComponent implements OnInit {
  missionList!: IMission[];
  selectedMission!: IMission;
 

  constructor(private service: SpacexapiService) {}

  getMission(): void {
    this.service.getMission().subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.missionList = resp;
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }

  onSelect(mission: IMission): void {
    this.selectedMission = mission;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMission();
  }
}
```

Displaying the Data in The Parent Component *missionList*

**This is working** The nested data from *links* is being displayed here just fine

```js
<ul class="missions" 
 
*ngIf="missionList">
    <li *ngFor="let mission of missionList | keys"   
(click)="onSelect(mission)"  
<span>{{mission.mission_name}}</span> -- {{mission.launch_year}}
        <p>{{mission.details}}</p>
        <aside><img [src]="mission?.links?.mission_patch_small" /></aside>
    </li>
</ul>

<app-missiondetails>[mission]="selectedMission"></app-missiondetails>
```

Keys Pipe

```js
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
    let keys: any = Object.keys(value),
      data: any = [];
    keys.forEach((key: any) => {
      data.push(value[key]);
    });
    return data;
  }
```

Child Component *missionDetails*

```js
export class MissiondetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() mission!: IMission;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Lastly, Here's How I Try to Display the Data on the Child and where I receive the error.

```js
<ul *ngIf="mission">
    <li><span>{{mission.mission_name}}</span> {{mission.launch_year}}
        <p>{{mission.details}}</p>
        <p>{{mission.links | json}}</p>
        <aside><img [src]="mission?.links?.mission_small_patch" /></aside>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would investigate the `onSelect` method and the `keys` pipe.

Comment: In your service file you should try returning the result as an observable like this `return this.http.get<IMission[]>(this.baseURL) as Observable<IMission[]>;` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study your returned object more, consider below extract...

```json
"links": {
      "mission_patch": "https://images2.imgbox.com/40/e3/GypSkayF_o.png",
      "mission_patch_small": "https://images2.imgbox.com/3c/0e/T8iJcSN3_o.png",
      "reddit_campaign": null,
      "reddit_launch": null,
      "reddit_recovery": null,
      "reddit_media": null,
      "presskit": null,
      "article_link": "https://www.space.com/2196-spacex-inaugural-falcon-1-rocket-lost-launch.html",
      "wikipedia": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DemoSat",
      "video_link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a_00nJ_Y88",
      "youtube_id": "0a_00nJ_Y88",
      "flickr_images": []
    },
```

In your interface you have stated `links: ILinks[];` implying that links is an array, unfortunately from your object `links` is an object.

So the first step in resolving the problem is changing this to `links: ILinks;`

The next thing to note is the name of your properties...

In your interface you define `mission_small_patch` but your properties you call `mission_patch_small`. Aligning this solves your problem

[See this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lsktpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fspacexapi.service.ts)

Comment: hey thanks for pointing out my mistake on the naming in the child components view. I didn't even realize it! This worked perfectly, I can't believe I overlooked the fact that I was declaring the nested object property as an array. Your solution helped and I fixed it